# Pathfinder: What to Spellbane to preserve my invisibility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, invisibility

I'm trying to figure out how the enemy could bypass or cancel my Greater Invisibility. Mind Blank should protect me from See Invisibility or True Seeing. And I'm using Spellbane to disable Dispel Magic, Greater Dispel Magic, Antimagic Field, Glitterdust and Invisibility Purge.

So other than using Blindsight, Spellbaning my Spellbane or simply finding and touching me, what can the enemy do to hit me with a targeted spell? Is there anything else I should Spellbane to stay invisible?

Comment: The title doesnt match the question

Answer (score 2):

Tremorsense and blindsense would also allow an enemy to pinpoint the square you are in, and there are ways to ignore the partial concealment such as [true strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-strike/) (yes its divination but its personal and target you so mind blank should not prevent it from working) and [improved precise shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-precise-shot-combat/). Best ways to gain tremorsense is with the wildshape, wildshape spells, or [phantom hunt](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantom-hunt/).

Technically the bag of flour trick will still work, it with both coat you, and provide a way to track your steps in the room. Its not magical so none of the spells actually block it, and greater invisibility doesnt get rid of new coverings.

Technically [whirlwind attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/whirlwind-attack-combat/) would allow them to attack you if within reach of the attack.

Finally, theres just having a good perception. Under the [invisibility rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Invisibility), you just need to pass a DC 20 to tell if there is an invisible creature within 30 feet. It kind of becomes an arms race between boosting perception and boosting stealth.

Comment: To clarify, my stealth is bad, I'm not trying to hide my location. I'm very sure the enemy will know where I'm. I merely want them to be unable to attack me with targeted (non-aoe) spells.

Comment: @enumag I was trying to give as complete an answer as possible, because it might matter for someone else, or even cover something you had no considered